# Hide InfoWindow before custom styles are applied

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm using Google Maps API [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) and I'm setting custom classes via javascript.

```js
 this.infoWindow.addEventListener("domready", this.handleContentReady);

 handleContentReady = () => {
   document.getElementsByClassName("gm-style-iw")[0]
     .parentElement
     .classList
     .add("custom-iw")
 }
```

The issue with it that when infoWindow is first loaded it doesn't have custom styles yet so it jumps from default to my custom styles

Is there a way to hide infoWindow before custom styles are applied?

Comment: Have you tried opening the infowindow out of the viewport (where it can't be seen)?

Comment: I've already found and added the solution. Thanks for giving an idea

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found an answer

The solution is to set pixelOffset for infoWindow to be outside map before window is open

```
this.infoWindow.setOptions({ pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2000) })
this.infoWindow.open(this.props.mapInstance, this.props.marker);
```

And to set it back after the content is ready

```
handleContentReady = () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("gm-style-iw")[0]
    .parentElement
    .classList
    .add("custom-iw")
  this.infoWindow.setOptions({ pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0) })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use CSS to extend styles for **gm-style-iw**

```
.gm-style-iw {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then for **custom-iw**

```
.custom-iw {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The **custom-iw** class will be added, it wil overwrite the **visibility** from **gm-style-iw**.

Comment: I've tried this one, this will only hide the content
Is there a way to hide tooltip completely?
Also note, that .custom-iw is the parent of .gm-style-iw and I can't set its styles until I add custom class to it